# Is it possible to get the values that have already been "pushed" with map?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, ecmascript-6

**If I have:**

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
```

**And I do:**

```
arr.map(function (val) {
    return val + 5;
});
```

**Is it possible to get the values that "map" currently/already has?**

I mean, for instance, in the last iteration, can you do *something like* this?:

```
arr.map(function (val) {

    // I realize now that values is actually a function in the
    // global scope that returns an empty array, but I meant
    // to use it as an example of a possible function that would
    // return the actual previous values.

    console.log(values()); // Logs [6, 7]
    return val + 5;
});
```

Or perhaps that'd be a misuse of `map`? Is there any other method through which I can achieve that, without pushing to an external array?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but in my opinion there is a bit of misuse.
[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) should only process data and return this processed data. For future code maintenance you should not write any side effects on that kind of code. 
If you want to do something for each element of array you can use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

When you want to write code easy to maintenance it is very helpful to keep some kind of constraints in your coding style. For example use `map` function only for intended use.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably use forEach, or need to rethink my code. However, I'm curious, how would I do it? I virtually just realized that `values()` is actually a function, I just meant to use it as an example, but it actually returns something! I'm confused as to what `values()` even is, it returns an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, never seen a map like this. I normaly use a map variable for maps. And for those you need an iterator to get the values in it.

How you are going towrite that iterator is another story. Will perhaps work with the regular (variable type)::iterator it.

Comment: Do you possibly mean [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values)?